# Typescript Generics NOT with type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say i have an array of types:

```
const arr: Foo[]: [
  a: Foo<A>,
  b: Foo<B>,
  c: Foo<C>,
];
```

How to limit the array to be NOT a type

```
const arr: Foo<Not<B>>[]: [
  a: Foo<A>,
  b: Foo<B>, // error
  c: Foo<C>,
];
```

Comment: Can you show how `Foo` is defined?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is to use the [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) utility type to specify a susbet of the type parameters that `Foo` can accept, something like this

```js
type Foo<T> = {
    value: T
}

type Bar = string | boolean | number
type BarWithoutBoolean = Exclude<Bar, boolean>

const arr: Foo<BarWithoutBoolean>[] = [
    { value: 1     },
    { value: "abc" }, 
    { value: true  } // Err
]
```